# Conditional Module instantiation in Chisel

Tags: scala, chisel

I'm trying to instantiate one of two chisel Module according to boolean parameter.

```
val useLib = true
val myModule = if(useLib) Module(new MyModule1()) else Module (new MyModule2())
```

But that doesn't work. Chisel doesn't recognize `io` interface :

```
[error] /path/to/source/mysource.scala:59:13: value io is not a member of Any
[error]   myModule.io.pdm <> io.pdm
[error]            ^
```

And of course, `MyModule1()` and `MyModule2()` have same io interfaces.

Is it possible to conditionally instantiate Module() as we do with preprocessor in C or C++ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written a new doc about upgrading from Chisel 3.4 to 3.5 that deals with this issue. It's not live on the website yet but will be once Chisel 3.5.0-RC2 is released. Here's a link to the doc: https://gist.github.com/jackkoenig/4949f6a455ae74923bbcce10dbf846b5#value-io-is-not-a-member-of-chisel3module

In sort, from Scala's perspective, `MyModule1` and `MyModule2` actually do **not** have the same interface, even though they are structurally the same. The trick is to factor out that interface into a named `Bundle` class and then use that in each of those modules. You then make each `Module` extend a `trait` that has that interface, and then Scala will know that the interfaces are the same.

For more information and examples, see the above linked doc.